# Group and choose max pair SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, hadoop

I have a table which has two columns.

```
create table txns( 
  person varchar(255),
  fruit varchar(255)
  );
```

This is a log table. 
I have sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e4bbd/6).

This is as far as I am able to get with the sql query.

In essence, For every person, which is the most frequent fruit he has eaten.

I have both Oracle and MySql at my place.
In the future, it would also be deployed on hadoop (via Hive/Impala etc).
Thus a non-db centric answer would be best. 
But pls also do provide a db centric answer if there is such only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following query would run both in Oracle and MySQL.

```
select k.person, k.fruit from
(
  select person,fruit,count(fruit) as cnt
  from txns
  group by person,fruit
) k
join
(
  select t.person,max(t.cnt) mxCnt
  from
  (
    select person,fruit,count(fruit) as cnt
    from txns
    group by person,fruit
  )t
group by t.person
) s
on s.person = k.person
and s.mxCnt = k.cnt 
order by k.person
```

Comment: Hi, I came up the almost the same solution yesterday. Just want to know is this computationally waay more intensive than the Oracle's Rank

Comment: Rank I guess is well optimized for the purpose, but to get a definite answer, we can run both these queries in a loop for some thousand times and compare the time taken.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e4bbd/118)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table txns(

  person varchar(255),
  fruit varchar(255)
  );

insert into txns
values ('alpha','apple');

insert into txns
values ('charlie','cherry');

insert into txns
values ('bravo','banana');

insert into txns
values ('alpha','apple');

insert into txns
values ('bravo','banana');

insert into txns
values ('alpha','apricot');

insert into txns
values ('bravo','berry');
```

**Query 1**:

```
with tab as (
select person, fruit,count(1) cnt,  
       max(count(1)) over (partition by person) m_cnt
  from txns
 group by person, fruit)
select person, fruit, cnt, m_cnt
  from tab
 where cnt = m_cnt
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e4bbd/118/0)**:

```
|  PERSON |  FRUIT | CNT | M_CNT |
|---------|--------|-----|-------|
|   alpha |  apple |   2 |     2 |
|   bravo | banana |   2 |     2 |
| charlie | cherry |   1 |     1 |
```

Answer (score 1):

For **Oracle**-

```
select x.person,x.fruit
from ( select person, fruit, count(*) ct,rank() over (partition by person 
                                                      order by count(*) desc) as rank
         from txns
group by person, fruit) x
where rank=1;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e4bbd/130)

### **The "non DB centric" idea is-**

1. You first find out for each person, how many time a particular fruit appears in the table (or how many time the fruit was eaten). This is done by `person, fruit,count(*)`.
2. Then you need to find out which fruit was most eaten by the `PERSON` i.e. essentially the `fruit` that holds the highest `RANK` or position, in this case a `DESC`ending order of `count(*)` would place the most eaten fruit in `RANK`=1 for each person (`partition by person`).
3. Once you are done ranking, you just need to select the first `RANK` for each `Person` which would essentially be the most eaten fruit by the person.

This is a perfect example of Oracle's analytical function [`RANK()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions123.htm).

### **Why use `RANK`, you ask?**

Your boss may change his mind & may ask you "Hey prog_guy, I changed my mind, I not only want the most eaten fruit by the fruit eater, I also want the 3rd most eaten fruit as well". What do you do? Scramble to write another query? No, you take the same query and change `rank=1` to `rank in (1,3)` and BAM! you now have the most eaten fruit and the third most eaten fruit (if any) by the fruit eaters.

AND / OR

Your boss may change his mind again and say "Hey prog_guy, forget about most eaten fruits, now I want you to get the least eaten fruit" What do you do? Scram again for a new query? Nope! You change the `desc` to `asc` in the `partition by` and BAM! you now have the least eaten fruit by the fruit eaters.

---

Some detail about `RANK()` equivalent of Oracle in MySQL [here](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1280#460). A little bit of info related to `RANK()` equivalent in Hive, [here](http://grokbase.com/t/hive/user/097mrr58sk/dense-rank-equivalent-in-hive).